# Checking a user is present in a group using aws lambda java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to my aws lambda function to return a list of IAM groups that a particular user is in.

I read the java sdk and found `getGroupList()`, but not sure how to use it.
also i could not find any sample code to do the same.

Comment: It returns a List of Strings.  What specific issue are you having?

Comment: @stdunbar In the documentation its mentioned to use AmazonIdentityManagement , but when i am trying, eclipse does not show this class, instead it shows cognitoIdentity classes.So i am not really sure how to proceed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't help you with Eclipse but this is pretty straight forward if you use a build environment like [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/).  Eclipse should be able to import this fine.  You have two files.  The first, `pom.xml` lives at the root of your code.  So if you've got your code in a directory called `iam` the `pom.xml file lives there.  It looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example.aws</groupId>
    <artifactId>iam-list</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-iam</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.810</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Next, your source code will live in the directory `src/main/java/com/example/aws/iam` inside of, in this example, `iam` and be named `IamUser.java`.  It **must** live in this directory for maven to be able to find it.  It looks like:

```
package com.example.aws.iam;

import com.amazonaws.services.identitymanagement.AmazonIdentityManagement;
import com.amazonaws.services.identitymanagement.AmazonIdentityManagementClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.identitymanagement.model.Group;
import com.amazonaws.services.identitymanagement.model.ListGroupsForUserRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.identitymanagement.model.ListGroupsForUserResult;

public class IamUser {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        AmazonIdentityManagement amazonIdentityManagement = AmazonIdentityManagementClientBuilder.standard().build();

        ListGroupsForUserRequest listGroupsForUserRequest = new ListGroupsForUserRequest().withUserName("stdunbar");
        ListGroupsForUserResult listGroupsForUserResult = amazonIdentityManagement.listGroupsForUser(listGroupsForUserRequest);

        for( Group nextUserGroup: listGroupsForUserResult.getGroups() ) {
            System.out.println( "user is in group " + nextUserGroup.getGroupName() );
        }
    }
}
```

It's very important to understand that your AIM credentials need to be setup to be able to run this.  See [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/setup-credentials.html) for details on how to do that.  The code I'm showing is using the `default` credential profile so that one will need to have IAM permissions to run this code on the console.

This is a command line version - obviously you'll need to role this into your Lambda but this should get you started.  Your Lambda will need permission to run this too.

Comment: ThankYou sir, I made the changes in pom.xml. Also i added aws-java-sdk-1.11.811.jar in build path. And it works..!!  @stdunbar